# Getting IllegalStateException while coming back without completing a call intent

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, illegalstateexception

In my application, I have a viewpager inside and activity.

From one of the fragments, on a button click, I am firing an intent to view the dial box for making a call using `intent.ACTION_VIEW`

It works fine in most of the devices including `2.3.5`, `4.0.8` and `4.1`, but in `LG Optimus 4.0.3 (L5)` , it is asking the user to select among the `Message` and `Call` actions in a dialog. If I press the call button and then press back button, it works OK. But if I press back button without selecting any of the two, the app is crashing with the exception,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

The same intent codes works fine in LG Optimus, if there is no fragments present.

I tried the fixes for similar error but they are not working.

I tried committing the fragment using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

I also tried with this code in my activity's saveInstanceState

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Could anybody help me with this?

**EDIT :**

Error log:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:445)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:164)
    at com.sample01.android.activity.ExtensionActivity.onBackPressed(ExtensionActivity.java:499)
    at com.sample01.android.activity.Main.onResume(MainActivity.java:328)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1156)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4710)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this issue.

I tried checking for the `exit status` together with removing the super call in savedInstanceState.

`super.onSaveInstanceState( savedInstanceState );`

I was committing the fragments allowing state loss due to which my app was exiting.

I tried setting my app's `EXIT STATUS` as false.

Now it is checking for the exit status in the onBackpress() and it works fine!

Thanks to this [**`POST`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261438/1237656) which helped me in finding s solution.! Even the comments for that answer are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ProgressDialog stop it and add some test like : if ( progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){ stopProgressBarDialog(); }