# Any side effect to solve "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" by using commitAllowingStateLoss

Tags: android

Previously, we have no problem displaying the following `DialogFragment`

[image]

```
// Triggered by button click.
private void openFromCloud() {      
    LoadFromCloudTaskFragment loadFromCloudTaskFragment = new LoadFromCloudTaskFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(loadFromCloudTaskFragment, "loadFromCloudTaskFragment").commit(); 
}
```

However, if we tend to display the same `DialogFragment` after pressing OK button on the following `Intent`, an error will occur.

[image]

```
private void openFromCloud() {      
    startActivityForResult(Utils.getGoogleAccountCredential().newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                Utils.getGoogleAccountCredential().setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                LoadFromCloudTaskFragment loadFromCloudTaskFragment = new LoadFromCloudTaskFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(loadFromCloudTaskFragment, "loadFromCloudTaskFragment").commit();
            }
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

---

Here are the detailed error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {org.yccheok.xxx.gui/org.yccheok.xxx.gui.XXXFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1310)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
    at org.yccheok.xxx.gui.XXXFragmentActivity$1.run(XXXFragmentActivity.java:107)
    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4591)
    at org.yccheok.xxx.gui.XXXFragmentActivity.onActivityResult(XXXFragmentActivity.java:102)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
    ... 11 more
```

I can simply "solve" the problem by using `commitAllowingStateLoss` instead of `commit`.

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(loadFromCloudTaskFragment, "loadFromCloudTaskFragment").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

I don't really understand the documentation regarding `commitAllowingStateLoss`.

> Like commit() but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's
>   state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if
>   the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should
>   only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change
>   unexpectedly on the user.

This is based on suggestion from [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

I don't really get the point **it is okay for the UI state to change unexpectedly on the user.**? May I know what is the possible side effect for using `commitAllowingStateLoss`? Any steps I can produce such side effect?

Comment: See this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information about why this exception occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is kind of "race condition" event.

Imagine a situation, when device is being rotated just before your `commitAllowingStateLoss()` call. AFAIK, the following occurs:

- `onSaveInstanceState()` callback(activity store it's state **with no fragment present** at the moment(since you haven't committed anything yet)
- `commitAllowingStateLoss` is executed **adding fragment** to the activity
- `Activity` is recreated, restoring it's state to the moment, when there were **no your fragment added**

In my opinion, it cause hardly predictable situations, such as:

- `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: FragmentB has target not in fragment manager: FragmentA` if you are using `Fragment.setTargetFragment()` for any reason
- your fragment can simply be missing from the view

Anyway, I'm not 100% sure about that, but I'm having lots of unexpected `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` exceptions in my app, and trying to find a solution too.

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Comment: nah anh I found out what the issue was...it was because the fragment which was trying to be had a target fragment which wasn't in the backstack

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't have this problem anymore. I got a similar problem. I solved put fragment transition code in onResume function. I have put a flag to indicate if result was ok. If it's true then inside onResume method I did transition to other Fragment.

Comment: Yes, I also believe that this is the correct way to do it. There's no need to use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` in this case either. :)

Comment: If the suggestion we are talking about here isn't clear... this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16265733/844882) uses this approach and solves the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the follow code in Activity.java

```
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG, mWindow.saveHierarchyState());
    Parcelable p = mFragments.saveAllState();
    if (p != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG, p);
    }
    getApplication().dispatchActivitySaveInstanceState(this, outState);
}
```

key codes  ===>mFragments.saveAllState()

if you commit after onSaveInstanceState then the state of the fragment will not be saved