# "Failure Delivering Result " - onActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `LoginActivity` (User Logs in). It is basically its own `Activity` that is themed like a dialog (to appear as if a dialog). It appears over a `SherlockFragmentActivity`. What I want is:  If there is a successful login, there should be two `FragmentTransaction`'s to update the view. Here is the code:

In `LoginActivity`, if successful login,

```
setResult(1, new Intent());
```

In `SherlockFragmentActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == 1) {
        LoggedStatus = PrefActivity.getUserLoggedInStatus(this);
        FragmentTransaction t = MainFragmentActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SherlockListFragment mFrag = new MasterFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();

        // Set up Main Screen
        FragmentTransaction t2 = MainFragmentActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SherlockListFragment mainFrag = new FeaturedFragment();
        t2.replace(R.id.main_frag, mainFrag);
        t2.commit();
    }
}
```

It crashes on the first commit, with this LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32072): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1299)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1310)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at com.kickinglettuce.rate_this.MainFragmentActivity.onActivityResult(MainFragmentActivity.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
E/AndroidRuntime(32072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
```

Comment: how did you call startActivityForResult()

Answer (score 300, accepted):

First of all, you should read my [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information (it talks about why this exception happens and what you can do to prevent it).

Calling `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is more of a hack than a fix. State loss is bad and should be avoided at all costs. At the time that `onActivityResult()` is called, the activity/fragment's state may not yet have been restored, and therefore any transactions that happen during this time will be lost as a result. This is a very important bug which must be addressed! (Note that the bug only happens when your `Activity` is coming back after having been killed by the system... which, depending on how much memory the device has, can sometimes be rare... so this sort of bug is not something that is very easy to catch while testing).

Try moving your transactions into `onPostResume()` instead (note that `onPostResume()` is always called after `onResume()` and `onResume()` is always called after `onActivityResult()`):

```
private boolean mReturningWithResult = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mReturningWithResult = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (mReturningWithResult) {
        // Commit your transactions here.
    }
    // Reset the boolean flag back to false for next time.
    mReturningWithResult = false;
}
```

This might seem a little weird, but doing this sort of thing is necessary to ensure that your `FragmentTransaction`s are always committed *after* the `Activity`'s state has been restored to its original state (`onPostResume()` is guaranteed to be called after the `Activity`'s state has been restored).

Comment: In Fragments, I'm using onResume in the absence of onPostResume. I haven't seen the issue again, but perhaps you want to comment on this.

PS. Thanks a lot for your insightful posts!

Comment: Yes, doing this in `Fragment#onResume()` is fine. This is because `FragmentActivity#onPostResume()` calls `FragmentActivity#onResumeFragments()`, which calls `FragmentManager#dispatchResume()`, which calls `Fragment#onResume()` for each of the activity's fragments. Therefore, `Fragment#onResume()` is called after `FragmentActivity#onPostResume()` so there won't be a problem (you can check out the [source code](http://goo.gl/Lo1Z1T
) for each respective class to verify this for yourself... or you can just just me :P). And thanks! Glad you thought they were insightful. :)

Comment: @Alex, If the dialogfragment makes a network call, and the Home button is pressed before the dialogfragment gets the async response, invoking this.dismiss() within the async response will cause a state loss exception. In this scenario, when should dismiss() be invoked so that there is no state loss? Note that request and response are within the dialogfragment, not within the activity.

Comment: @crazyhorse In that case, it might be a good idea to cancel the async task and/or raise a flag to ensure that `dismiss()` isn't called inside `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()` (the dialog will be dismissed automatically by the `FragmentManager` in the case that the activity goes in the background, so there's no need for you to dismiss the dialog yourself after the activity has gone away anyway).

Comment: @AlexLockwood, yes I use a flag now - I wanted to avoid using a boolean here, but it seems to be unavoidable in some cases.

Comment: Did not know about `onPostResume()`. Fixed my problem (I was creating a dialog fragment in `onResume()` after cancelling a system dialog from a pending intent, which crashed my app).

Comment: Before implementing this solution, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30429551/253704) to see why it's a hack (along with many others). The real solution is a one line fix.

Comment: @twig I do call `super.onActivityResult()` in my answer (and the OP does in the question as well), so I'm not sure how the link you posted solves the problem.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Sorry about that. I missed that line when looking through your solution and lumped your fix along with the other hacks. Updated post accordingly

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks for the detailed explanation. I had been using `commitAllowingStateLoss` all the while for a 2+ years old app. But, I never observe any strange thing. May I know, if state loss happens, does it happen in the following sequence? history chart fragment commit in onActivityResult -> restore state happen and history chart is whipped out from fragment manager -> onResume called.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Also, may I know is "restoring state" you mentioned in your article, does it has anything to do with `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`? As, I usually preserve my variables in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, and restore them back in `onCreate(Bundle)`. Is "restoring state" referring to what I'm doing in `onCreate(Bundle)`, or it is another thingy?

Comment: Does this imply that you shouldn't really ever do anything (at least reference anything) in `onActivityResult` except set the `resultCode` and `data` to a global variable then do the operations in `onResume`?

Comment: @ono No, there are still plenty of valid ways to override `onActivityResult()`. You just have to be aware that `onActivityResult()` is called before the activity/fragments have restored their saved state. So for example, if you started an activity for a result and then modified a text view's text upon returning in `onActivityResult()`, it's possible that the updated text will be overwritten afterwards when the activity/fragment's view state is restored.

Comment: @AlexLockwood my problem is that I'm trying to set a text in a TextView from the data in the Intent from onActivityResult but my view is null. Only if android removed my activity

Comment: @AlexLockwood I have same issue with  onRequestPermissionsResult https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190966

Comment: As of support lib 22.2.1, `onActivityResult` in `Fragment` is invoked after `onStart`. So I think if u wanna show dialog fragment in `Fragment.onActivityResult`, it's safe to invoke `show()` directly without any workaround.

Comment: @ThuyTrinh Is there a bug that you know of that confirms this? I wasn't aware of any changes to the fragment lifecycle recently.

Comment: @AlexLockwood thank you for this post. In you blog you say that transactions should be commited after Activity#onPostResume. But at the same time you say that they can be commited in Activity#onCreate (which runs even before onResume). I'm sure that I've misunderstood something, so can you explain.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617600/illegal-state-exception-in-androidcan-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinsta

Comment: Just got this error on *Android O (8.0)* with the latest *support lib 26.0.2*. The bug is still present. The workaround in this answer fixes the problem. I got this error after calling `show()` on a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @alexeypolusov My understanding is that it is safe to commit transactions from `Activity#onCreate` because that is guaranteed to happen before any fragment state restoration and the framework dictates this is the right place to override the default restoration of a fragment if you choose. So there is a window between `onCreate` and `onPostResume` where you have to wait for the state restoration to finish before making transactions.

Comment: @AlexLockwood: What about this method?
```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
```
I will use this to detect app resume (not only one activity)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPostResume() says "Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final setup after application resume code has run." - are you sure I should use this? My app has to open different fragments on startup under certain conditions. I 've used onResume() of the main activity for a few years now. No problem  I just found this thread because I'm looking for a rarely occurring illegal state in onSaveInstanceState() of this activity...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResume()

void onResumeFragments ()

This is the fragment-orientated version of onResume() that you can override to perform operations in the Activity at the same point where its fragments are resumed. Be sure to always call through to the super-class.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the @Alex Lockwood answer but using a `Runnable`:

```
private Runnable mOnActivityResultTask;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mOnActivityResultTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (mOnActivityResultTask != null) {
        mOnActivityResultTask.run();
        mOnActivityResultTask = null;
    }
}
```

In case you're running *Android 3.0* and above with *lambdas*, use this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mOnActivityResultTask = () -> {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather go with runnable, since that lets you write the logic close to where it happens. In my case it's coming from rx subscriber.

Answer (score -1):

your logcat clearly says: *"Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"* -- your `Activity` is already dead at that point and could not return any results.

just move:

```
Intent in = new Intent();
setResult(1, in);
```

to the place in your `Activity` where it's still alive, and everything will be fine.
and don't forget to `finish()` your `Activity` to deliver the result.

Comment: Thanks.  `finish()` is last thing I am doing.  I had the intent code just above it.,  I moved it up top and same error.  I am adding code to answer...

Comment: One more point on last comment. I actually don't see toast.  But when I reenter app after crash I am logged in.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()` to solve this problem.

Reason: your `ft.commit()` method was toggled after `onSaveInstanceState`.

Answer (score -1):

In my Case I faced the same issues Because of the Following

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setIntents();

}


private void setIntents(){
    Intent searchConstaints=new Intent();
    searchConstaints.putExtra("min",20);
    searchConstaints.putExtra("max",80);
    setResult(101,searchConstaints);
    finish();
}
```

Solved by re-arranging the function Calls within **onBackPressed()**

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    setIntents();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```