# IllegalStateException if try to display dialog from onActivityResult

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-bluetooth, onactivityresult

I am developing an application which needs user to enable Bluetooth. For this once the desired button is clicked, an intent is thrown to enable Bluetooth. I am using the following code:

```
public static final int ENABLE_BT = 1;

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                .getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent, ENABLE_BT);

        } 
    }

});
```

Further if the user does not enable Bluetooth, I want a Dialog to be displayed. The class for this is as follows:

```
public class MessageDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Bluetooth to proceed")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

The `onActivityResult()` method is as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == ENABLE_BT)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //button.setText("err");
                DialogFragment dialog = new MessageDialog();
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Warning !");
            } 
}
```

The problem is that as soon I don't enable Bluetooth, the application terminates with and `IllegalStateException`. The log relevant log is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.iskh.btchat.start/com.iskh.btchat.start.FirstActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I am unable to understand how displaying the `Dialog` is illegal. I have checked, this error is only when the code which shows `Dialog` is present. If that code is commented out, then the app runs as expected. And I have also tested the `Dialog`. Elsewhere it displays as expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Postpone the show-call of your Dialog to FragmentActivity#onResumeFragments() or Activity#onPostResume() instead of onActivityResult

This is answered in ["Failure Delivering Result " - onActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265733/failure-delivering-result-onactivityforresult/)

Full Explanation:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html