# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException in onRequestPermissionsResult()

Tags: android, permissions, illegalstateexception, onsaveinstancestate

I am working with sd card and so trying to get permission in runtime. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FileListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 111;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

         ...................
         ................
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    FileListFragment fileListFragment = FileListFragment.newInstance(0);  // **Error line**
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fileListFragment)
                .commit();
                } else {

                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

.............................
..................................
..........................

}
```

As soon as I am allow the permission it is throwing **"Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.kaushik.fileexplorer/com.kaushik.fileexplorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"**. Here is the details logcat:

```
08-23 16:49:29.497 3215-3215/com.kaushik.fileexplorer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.kaushik.fileexplorer, PID: 3215
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.kaushik.fileexplorer/com.kaushik.fileexplorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1533)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1551)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:662)
                                                                            at com.kaushik.fileexplorer.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:76)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

What is problem in that code?

Comment: add your `onSaveInstanceState`  code?

Comment: Have you added the permission in `manifest` file? You can't ask for permission at run time if you didn't.

Comment: @SohailZahid I did not override onSaveInstanceState() at all.

Comment: I have added permission. it is working fine for sub-6.0 devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add  commitAllowingStateLoss()

```
 FileListFragment fileListFragment = FileListFragment.newInstance(0);  // **Error line**
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fileListFragment)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

Answer (score 3):

This Error is because the Activity State is Not Saved and you are adding Fragment before it.

**Use This Code :**

```
FileListFragment fileListFragment = FileListFragment.newInstance(0); 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fileListFragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

And Override Your **onSaveInstanceState()** method and remove the **super()** from it.

Answer (score 2):

using commitAllowingStateLoss() is more like a hacky fix.

This problem is very similar to this one and is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265733/failure-delivering-result-onactivityforresult/18345899#18345899).

Instead it's better to set a boolean flag in `onRequestPermissionsResult` and use this in `onPostResume` (for Activitys) or `onResume` (for Fragments) to commit the transaction.