# Why my android app is crashing periodically?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, xamarin

My application crashes whenever my location is changed.
Application structure is simple: there is one **Activity** and a many **fragments**. Conclusion fragment is carried out as follows:

```
ItemsFragment itemsFragment = new ItemsFragment () {GroupID = groupID, CurrentGroup = currentGroup};
itemsFragment.RetainInstance = true;
var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
fragmentManager.Replace (Resource.Id.flContent, (SupportFragment) itemsFragment);
fragmentManager.AddToBackStack (null);
fragmentManager.Commit ();
```

I use C # Xamarin, but java principle is the same, only slightly different syntax. Help a newbie android-developers to understand the reason.

On the mobile device produces an error:

```
“Unfortunately App has Stopped”
```

Where only can be put **try... catch** and got this error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: Here I have answered the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101937/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-onrequestpermissionsresult/39103284#39103284

Comment: There are tons of those question on stackoverflow, each of them provide lots of information about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are sometimes replacing fragments after your Activity has paused. The easiest way to fix it is to use `fragmentManager.CommitAllowingStateLoss();`

As @user13 mentioned, it is the easiest, and the worst way.
If you want a good solution, you should check if the `Activity` state is Ok to replace fragment before actually replacing it

Comment: The easiest and the worst one.

Comment: Explain how to make the best

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should try with Handler

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ItemsFragment itemsFragment = new ItemsFragment () {GroupID = groupID, CurrentGroup = currentGroup};
                itemsFragment.RetainInstance = true;
                var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
                fragmentManager.Replace (Resource.Id.flContent, (SupportFragment) itemsFragment);
                fragmentManager.AddToBackStack (null);
                fragmentManager.Commit ();
            }
        });
```