# Crash due to quick Back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I press the Back button once, the app exits just fine. But when I press the [Back] button repeatedly and quickly, the app crashes (ref.the attached stack trace). There happens even without any fragment transaction performed. Is there a cure for this?

```
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:475)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:174)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2145)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2375)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-06 05:41:50.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa

Comment: @SankarV I tried all methods provided at the SO link to no avail. Then I figure out my stupid mistake (mentioned in the edit). Thank for the link then. That question seems old (from Sep 2011) so I guess Google had already fixed all the described bugs.

Comment: Remove your edit and add it in the Answer so that questions won't appear unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out my stupid mistake. I called `super.onStop()` when overriding the activity's `onPause()`!