# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState in FragmentActivity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This is the code which i have written.i could not able to find when this functionality crashes but it works sometimes.

```
public class ListFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  main();
  IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter("com.venkat.listfragment");
  registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter1);
  // register reciever intent filter.

}
public void main(){
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter("com.venkat.listfragment");
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter1);
     List_Fragment ls_fragment = new List_Fragment();
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(android.R.id.content, ls_fragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        main();

    }
};}
```

I have four tabs,When i click on one tab it displays the corresponding screen and from that screen i am navigating another screen with in the same tab.but to get back to the previous screen when i clicked on same tab i have written a broadcast receiver for that.

i am getting this error:

```
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.venkat.listfragment } in com.iheartsalesevent.main.ListFragmentActivity$1@44a89218
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:905)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1354)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:493)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.venkat.main.ListFragmentActivity.main(ListFragmentActivity.java:65)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.venkat.main.ListFragmentActivity$1.onReceive(ListFragmentActivity.java:89)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
08-19 10:13:51.436: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     ... 9 more
```

I referred so many links related to this issue but those are not resolve my problem.

Comment: I think this is tied to these kind of problems reported and discussed in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7469082/1051783).

Comment: Please stop misusing the quote sign ">" in your questions/answers. This is not meant to be used for non-quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Registering BroadcastReceiver in `onResume()` and unregistering in `onPause()` will solve the issue. If needed, you can use `onStart()` / `onStop()` as well.