# Android app crashes when reopening and replacing fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

For my current application that I'm writing I have implemented a navigation drawer (the default Android way with backwards compatibility).
So from the nav drawer you select a menu element and then I do this (addPreviousToBackStack is always false for testing):

```
private void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment, final boolean addPreviousToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container, fragment);
    if(addPreviousToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getTag());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    currentFragment = fragment;
}
```

So that works like a charm when I start the application. Then I close the application using the back button. If I then reopen the app (no matter how: via the long press home button or via the shortcut) the app starts at the initial screen (onCreate is called) and then I open the nav drawer and select a menu item and the application crashes.

This is my exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

And it happens exactly on my line where I do

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I have no clue why I'm getting this when the app is re-opened and not when the app is initially opened. Any clues??

Comment: This an Android vintage issue :) Maybe [my answer from a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13987336/1051783) will help you.

Comment: Hmm, none of your good ways or Un-orthodox ways work for me... I'm trying the on a 4.3 device (galaxy nexus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the context of your use case, but calling `fragmentTransaction.commitAllowStateLoss();` should not cause the crash anymore. However, you need to assume the risk that your state info will be lost on fragment. 
 
Also, this line `currentFragment = fragment;` seems to me a cause of memory leak. If Android wants to cleanup the fragment you will prevent it by keeping a strong reference to the fragment. Don't use it ...

Comment: Addding fragmentTransaction.commitAllowStateLoss(); does not work, it keeps on crashing as before... Then how should I keep a reference to the fragment. I sometimes need to interact to the fragment, that's why I keep in there...

Comment: `getFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container)` is how you can get the Fragment instance. Then you'll perform an upcast to your fragment class if you need to access a particular method.

Comment: I tested again with the commitAllowStateLoss() and that seems to give me the Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed exception

Comment: That's easy to fix: check if `getActivity()` is null

Comment: The activity will never be null as I run this piece of code from the activity... I tried to surround with a check if (!this.isFinishing) {} and that seems to be working, however I'm not sure if I can trust that fix... Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can you reveal more of your code? I'm interested in the context where you're calling above `replaceFragment(...)` method