# IllegalStateException - no references to my code in stacktrace

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-appcompat

this stacktrace was submitted to my project issue tracker.
As you there is no references to my code, so does anybody know how to fix it?
I'm using support library v19.0.1 and I can provide more details about device/platform if need

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:179)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onBackPressed(ActionBarActivity.java:250)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2099)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2575)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2329)
        at android.support.v7.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:250)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3344)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3317)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2464)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which is the API level of the device/emulator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa/10261438#10261438

Comment: it is the real device with API level 15. I am not using Fragments, I even don't call onSaveInstanceState anywhere in my project

Answer (score 0):

First change i made is

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container,new CatListFragment(null)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Second change is intercept onPause onStop and onResume for the activity, maintain a flag if application is in paused state(or any other way). Intention is not to call .commit() or .commitAllowingStateLoss() in paused state. Once app is resumed you can call the FragmentManager commit. Worked for me :)

Comment: Even if I do not use fragments?