# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I show a DialogFragment inside a button onClick event like below:

```
public void  onButtonClick() {
    myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Why does it cause IllegalStateException, may it called after onSaveInstanceState?
Here is the log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1377)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1395)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:637)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:616)
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
   at com.a.b.AFragment.editSex(AFragment.java:226)
   at com.a.b.AFragment.access$200(AFragment.java:46)
   at com.a.b.AFragment$3.onButtonClick(AFragment.java:134)
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713002/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc

Comment: Post some code with logcat

Comment: Please read this  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have looked at this link http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html, But I think the method will not be called after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: @Chandrakanth,thank you a lot, I have followed your suggestion.

Comment: Make sure you call through to super wherever appropriate. That includes `onResume`, `onStart`, `onCreate`, `onActivityCreate`, `onSaveInstanceState`, `onActivityResult` etc. That goes for fragments and for activities.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your show method call this

```
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

after adding fragment to

```
fragmentTransaction.add();
```

For reference

> Like commit but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change unexpectedly on the user.

Comment: sometimes it can be a good choice (of course not all the time) but you need to put this on manifest at the activity where is the fragment --> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection" (in my case worked)