# java.lang.IllegalStateException(Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState)

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, fragmentmanager

I am getting this error with following message in different scenario:

- Activity has been destroyed and
- Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I am writing an app where Two Activity interacting with each Other. **Activity-A** launch **Activity-B** using Intent. This **Activity-B** class have two fragment children. **Fragment-A** use public method of activity to launch another **Fragment-B**.

```
public void beginTransaction(ID id, Bundle bundle) {

        Fragment fragment = getFragmentItem(id);

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

**Fragment-B** every time call **finish()** to kill Activity-B hence control move back to **Activity-A** again. And same process repeat. After doing 2-3 time I am getting:

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState E/AndroidRuntime( 9008):**    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1354)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 9008):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1372)

so to avoid it I follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261438/2624806 and it started to give me

> **Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed**
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 9235):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1376)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 9235):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)

any suggestion what I am missing here.

**GOT IT** I got solution ..it is mistake happening in transaction for adding fragment. I was using **.add** instead to use **.replace** (as my requirement not to maintain stack) and use **commitAllowTransaction** to commit it. I read http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html as well and seems what I did could be costly but for normal fragment transaction mention work-around work great.

Comment: `commitAllowingStateLoss()` to `commit()`.

Comment: How are you calling finish from your fragment? With getActivity().finish()?

Comment: At what time you call the method beginTransaction (...)? 
[Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-commit-transaction-state-loss.html) 
 
"Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods."

Comment: Thanks, @Mdlc @ anderson_acs I did not write explicit code to finish Fragment, Fragment call public method beginTransaction() to launch another fragment, which replace existing fragment. any suggestion!

Comment: @user3249477 I tried it but it giving same result.

Comment: Since you want to remove Fragment-A and add Fragment-B, you need to use `FragmentTransaction.replace` instead of `FragmentTransaction.add`. Try and let me know whether it helps.

Comment: @Shubh can you post the entire code where you call finish

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As i can not comment on your question due to less reputation point.
 I assume this is your public method to change fragment.

```
public void beginTransaction(ID id, Bundle bundle)
```

In this method every time you are adding fragment to activity. So if you are adding fragment first time this will work fine but in case of second fragment you should use replace not add

```
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

I think after doing this you should not face this problem. or you can use 'replace' for both first and second fragment.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: If in case my requirement is like I can't use replace rather than add then how can I handle it?