# State Loss Management

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

I've an Activity A that contains a Login Fragment and an Activity B that contains a Home Fragment.
I've to start B from Login Fragment after a succesfully login request (async).
I've a callback listener inside the login fragment:

```
onSuccess(result) {
    startActivity(B);
}
```

Today I met this nice bug: [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa).

I think that's not properly a bug, anyway I don't know how to workaround that. [This blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) suggests to avoid transaction inside async callback methods, yeah but how? commitAllowingStateLoss() should be used as a last resort: in case, should I use it inside Home Fragment transaction in Activity B creation method?

Basically, what should I do to start another activity after async callback?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should use onPostExecute(result) in the AsyncTask:</strike>

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<parameters,...> {
...
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //if result successful start ActivityB
     }
}
```

Onpost fires after the asynctask is complete.
It runs on the UI thread so that should solve your problem.

Put this in your main activity:

```
public void  run(){
        //code you would normally have after task completes
    }
```

Then put this in your onSuccess:

```
mainactivity.runUIonthread()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using AsyncTask class provided by android framework, but loopj library: so I have a callback from a listener inside the fragment and the request is inside another class. Any way to simulate onPostExecute and on UI thread execution? Many thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer for loopj, let me know if it works.