# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

By clicking on the notification I post PendingIntent which is Intent with parameters;
In MyActivity I get this intent and pass it into the method `onNewIntent(getIntent());`
In this method, I take out my parameters, and depending on them to perform actions.
The problem is that when the app is closed or open - method is called and everything works properly. But if the application is minimized, then pressing the notification error output.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
        onNewIntent(getIntent());

    }

   ...
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Bundle arguments;
        Fragment fragment;
        String guest;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("group_id")) {
                int msg = extras.getInt("group_id");
                String hotel = extras.getString("hotel");
                switch (msg) {
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new PagerLogbookContainer();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_HOTEL, hotel);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                        setTitle(hotel);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        guest = extras.getString("guest");
                        String room = extras.getString("room");
                        fragment = new Guest();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
                        arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
                        arguments.putString("room", room);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "guest").commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        guest = extras.getString("guest");
                        fragment = new Survey();
                        arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString("guestid", guest);
                        arguments.putString("hotel", hotel);
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {

            fragment = new StatusInfo();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            setTitle("Статус инфо");

        }
    }
...

    }

}
```

ERROR LOG:

```
12-15 04:34:39.995      733-733/com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1383)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:507)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.MyActivity.onNewIntent(MyActivity.java:158)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1722)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1734)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:1742)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:978)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please post error log ?

Comment: the code on line 158 is causing the error. Can you tell which is the line?

Comment: fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: change the commit() to commitAllowingStateLoss() and check whether that is working

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa?rq=1