# Android ShowDialog : IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception, showdialog

In `runOnUiThread()` of an Activity, I'm trying to show a ProgressDialog.

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ProgressDialogFragment mProgressDialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
 mProgressDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, TAG);
```

Here `ProgressDialogFragment` extends `DialogFragment`. I have tested this in many devices and didn't get any crash. But whereas in Asus, I'm constantly getting the below crash whenever I show the dialog. OS version on Asus is 4.4.2 .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
       at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:155)
       at com.trimble.android.trimbleone.activity.ProgressDialogHandlerActivity.showProgressDialog(ProgressDialogHandlerActivity.java:72)
       at com.trimble.android.trimbleone.activity.UICallbackHandlerActivity$processThread$7.run(UICallbackHandlerActivity.java:222)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: which are those many devices? Version of those devices?

Comment: @PareshMayani Just an FYI, the only reason I edited further was to do a `Reject and Edit` of a questionable edit suggestion after yours.

Comment: @DanielNugent no problem! I just formatted the code to understand it perfectly and missed to format other required stuffs!

Comment: @PareshMayani Nexus, LG G3, Motorola, Those devices are running lollipop verison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}
```

don't make the call to `super()` on the `saveInstanceState` method. This was messing things up...

After some more research, this is a know bug in the support package.

If you need to save the instance, and add something to your `outState` `Bundle` you can use the following :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In the end the proper solution was (as seen in the comments) to use :

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

when adding or performing the `FragmentTransaction` that was causing the `Exception`.

The above solutions were fixing issues in the early support.v4 libraries from what I can remember. But if you still have issues with this you MUST also read [@AlexLockwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844882/alex-lockwood) 's blog : [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Summary from the blog post (but I strongly recommend you to read it) :

NEVER `commit()` transactions after `onPause()` on pre-Honeycomb, and `onStop()` on post-Honeycomb
Be careful when committing transactions inside `Activity` lifecycle methods. Use `onCreate()`, `onResumeFragments()` and `onPostResume()`
Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods
Use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` only as a last resort
**Updated** : For showing the `DialogFragment` using stateLoss use the following lines.

```
DialogFragment loadingDialog = createDialog();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(loadingDialog, "loading");
                    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}                                                                                                       This method should be added to the class that extends DialogFragment??

Comment: after this line mProgressDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, TAG); should I add transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); ??

Comment: If you want to save the data while changing the configuration then you have call the super method of onSaveInstanceState().
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss() is the last option for solving this problem.

Comment: When I add transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()  after mProgressDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, TAG) Im getting the following crash.  E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(:582)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(:578)

Comment: Do not call `dialog.show()` after calling `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()`. It basically is the same call. Doing so might give you an error saying something like

**Transaction is already committed.**

or

**Can't change tag of fragment.....**

since you might be calling `dialog.show(transaction,"some_new_tag")`.