# add Fragment java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

From an Activity, I call my method to add a new fragment:

```
protected void addFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment,
                               @NonNull String fragmentTag,
                               int containerViewId, int enterAnim, int exitAnim,
                               int popEnterAnim, int popExitAnim) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim, popEnterAnim, popExitAnim)
                .add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag);

        transaction = transaction.addToBackStack(null);             
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Most of cases all is perfect, but **very rarely** there is a crash (detected by Crashlytics):

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this
>   action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2044)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2067)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:680)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:634)
>          at com.compagny.ui.BaseActivity.addFragment(BaseActivity.java:1495)
>          at com.compagny.ui.BaseActivity.addFragment(BaseActivity.java:1472)
>          at com.compagny.ui.training.TrainingActivity.setupView(TrainingActivity.java:309)

I don't know why; have you got some suggestions for my investigation guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: consider advices in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The Activity can only transact fragments AFTER onResume and BEFORE onSaveInstanceState.

- onActivityResult happens before onResume (Not sure what test I did for this one, maybe this statement is invalid)
- While changing activities they are out of this state (As a callback of a async task)
- If they come minified to system  (As a callback of a async task)