# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState when get notification- Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, onesignal

When I get new notification, I redirect the user to a `AFragment` but get me bellow error.Bellow I get notification:

```
class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

    private final Context context;

    NotificationOpenedHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String link;
        if (data != null) {
            link = data.optString("link", null);
            if (link != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(link)) {
                try {
                    String idLang = new SessionManager(context).getIdLanguage();
                    if (idLang != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(idLang)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("LINK", link);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Throwable t = new Throwable(ex).fillInStackTrace();
                    FirebaseCrash.report(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from `MainActivity` redirect user to `AFragment` then redirect to `NotificationFragment` like bellow:

```
        if (getActivity() != null && isResumed() && !isRemoving()) {
            redirectNotification = false;
            NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString("URL_NOTIFICATION", urlNotification);
            notificationFragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_work_table_fragment,
                            notificationFragment,
                            getString(R.string.notification_fragment))
                    .addToBackStack(getString(R.string.notification_fragment))
                    .commit();
        }
```

But get me bellow error:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: Share the code of  onSaveInstanceState as well.

Comment: I don't use from onSaveInstanceState in my code.

Comment: Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa/10261438#10261438